# Spring security using LDAP authentication without using manager-dn and manager-password

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I am using Spring Security for ldap authentication and have this configuration on my spring-security.xml

```
        <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider  
                user-search-filter="xxxxx" 
                user-search-base=""
                group-search-filter="xxxxx"
                group-search-base=""
                group-role-attribute="cn"
                role-prefix="ROLE_">
        </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:ldap-server url="ldap://servername54389/dc=..." manager-dn="xxxx" manager-password="xxxx" />
```

This works well for me. However, we cannot put manager-dn and manager-password like this in the xml. Is there a way to avoid putting manager-password in the code and still have it work? If I simply remove manager-dn and manager-password in the xml, it does not work and gives Access denied error.

Any details/help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't use `manager-dn` and `manager-password` in *any* way, not just this way.That's for the server itself, and it bypasses some of its own semantics. Create accounts for your applications that have suitable (probably *not* all permissions, and use those.

Comment: You could add the details to a separate file some where on the file system, say in the application server where the application will be deployed and then read them from values from there